# PHP json_decode converts boolean to integer

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is my code:

```
$json = '{"1":{"show":true},"2":{"show":false}}';
echo '<pre>',print_r(json_decode($json, true)),'</pre>';exit;
```

Following is the output of the code.

[image]

How can I preserve the boolean values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That actually is how true/false is often interpreted. Just roll with it.

Comment: Everything is preserved.

Comment: Nothing to do with `json_decode` that's `print_r`'s doing ... try `var_dump` instead.

Comment: This is how [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) displays boolean values. You can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to get a more accurate representation.

Comment: And just because I imagine this might come up - the reason you've got a **1** at the end of the output in screenshot is because you're echo-ing the result of the `print_r` call

Comment: To add to @iainn 's comment, you would add a `,true` to the `print_r` for concat echo use, to have it return the content instead of the bool result.

Comment: Need a flag to close on "Thats how it works... nothing wrong here, move along" ...